# Refactor renaming variable in Android Studio Mac Shortcut doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

As on right click of variable in Android Studio, for renaming all specific variable in a file, there is shortcut for `Shift + F6` in this window:

[image]

But if I click `Shift + F6`, nothing happens.

Any idea?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

On Mac function buttons works by default. So you should click `Fn + Shift + F6`, or go to System Preferences -> Keyboard and change behaviour of F buttons.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton it saved my major time. I was literally frustrated about why function keys are not working in android studio in my new MacBook!!!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone whose macOS is 13(Ventura) or above,

[image]
[image]

(credit to @Sviatoslav Yakymiv)